# Typescript inlines .d.ts import after compile

Tags: typescript, webpack

So I've been trying to learn how to setup a project rather than always rely on ready boilerplates. Getting it up and running was easy enough but I'm having problems with type declarations. After compiling the code, .js file looks something like:

```js
import 'package/a/type.d.ts'
import A from 'package/a'
```

Now, because of it webpack throws an error:
`You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file.` presumably because it can't read that syntax.

Tried googling this but couldn't find anything similar and being new to this, I don't really know what I'm looking for.

webpack config:

```
{
    mode,
    entry: './src/index.tsx',
    target: 'web',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'app.bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.ts(x)?$/,
                use: 'ts-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                include: path.join(__dirname, '/src'),
            }
    },
    plugins: [new HTMLWebpackPlugin({
        template: 'src/index.html'
    })],
    resolve: {
        modules: ['node_modules'],
        extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js', '.json'] // necessary for importing other files
    }
}
```

tsconfig

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "module": "esnext",
    "target": "ES6",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "lib": [
      "esnext",
      "dom"
    ],
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "strict": true,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules/*"
  ],
  "include" : [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.tsx"
  ]
}
```

I'd be grateful for any suggestions.

Comment: You shouldn't need to import the `.d.ts` files manually. When you import a `foo` module, TypeScript will automatically look for the corresponding `foo.d.ts` file to get the types from.

Comment: @dwjohnston I'm not, typescript adds that on his own after compiling.

Comment: Omg, I'm a special one, I must've added it at some point or something and completely didn't notice it. Thanks for pointing that out!